# How do I use SUMIF function if the needed criteria for the range are values greater than one?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a question with regards to the SUMIF function, but before that I would like to show a brief illustration of how I am able to do it using long tables.

[image]

This is just an example, not the intended application of what I would be asking about.

Let's say there are three types of classrooms and each classroom has a "unique" set of chairs per classroom type. Like for a small classroom, there are 30 distinct chairs. If there is another small classroom in the floor, it has similar 30 distinct chairs. I would like to find the number of total unique chairs per floor.

So what I did for the red part is an IF statement that sets the value to 0 once there are no rooms of that type that appear in that floor. If there are rooms, whether it is one or more the value will still be the number of unique chairs per type of classroom. It won't be multiplied or anything because I am after the unique chairs.

Then I can get the total of unique chairs per floor through the table.

My question is, is there are way to get the sum using SUMIF function, so I don't have to create the additional red column? The SUMIF function has the following format:

=SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

I don't know what to put in the criteria to specify that the value in the range must be greater than one. Sure, I know how to put specific values, but I don't know what to do if what I want is all set of values greater than one.

So for short, I can do what I intend to do using tables in Excel but I want to be able to also do it through the SUMIF function.

Comment: So, `Number of Chairs` column is your desired output without red columns?

Comment: Why use SUMIF? You reference one value/cell IF true. A simple IF would suffice, I think. Something like: `=IF(B3=0,0,$E3)`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

To what I understand I guess you have another table where you write your value and another table where your formula are created, Try this copy paste down the formula in Cell B2

```
=IF(SUMIFS(J$2:J$4,$I$2:$I$4,$A2)>1,INDEX($H$2:$H$4,MATCH($A2,$I$2:$I$4,0),1),0)
```

Comment: The formula does work, but I was wondering if there was a way to get the 90, 120 and 80 values without having to create a separate table? To put it in relatively simpler words, like for example I want the total for the first floor to be 30*0 + 40*3 + 50*5 but for the 3 and 5 to be replaced by 1 because I only care if the first floor rooms are zero or nonzero because those are what are considered "unique values". Or in other words, as long as it is nonzero, you multiply 1 and not the actual value of the rooms.